# R xtable and table width

Tags: longtable, width, xtable

I have to fit a table with many columns to the width of a page, using `xtable` and `longtable` environment.

My R code is

```
library(xtable)

data <- matrix( data = 1000000000, ncol=14, nrow = 100)

x.big <- xtable(data,label='tabbig')

print(x.big,tabular.environment='longtable',
        floating=FALSE,include.rownames=FALSE, 
        hline.after = c(-1,nrow(x.big)),
        add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),
        command = "\\hline \\endhead "), file = "output.tex")
```

The resulting Latex output is

```
% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Sun Apr 10 00:21:26 2016
\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
  \hline \endhead 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
  1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 & 1000000000.00 \\
   \hline
\hline
\label{tabbig}
\end{longtable}
```

What trick to use to have the columns fit the pages?

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Comment: Did you consider `scalebox`?

Comment: `xtable(formatC(data),label='tabbig')`